Load custom compiled SQLite3 library into Python script
On macOS I have compiled my own version of SQLite 3 and moved that to /usr/local/lib
❯ ls /usr/local/lib
libsqlite3.dylib sqlite3

However I can't seem to load that version of the SQLite into my Python3 script. Checking version it shows the old one.
import os
import sqlite3

# Ensure the library path is set
os.environ['DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = '/usr/local/lib'

def check_sqlite_version():
    conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT sqlite_version();')
    version = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    print(f"SQLite version: {version}")
    conn.close()

check_sqlite_version()

Is above not the right way to accomplish that?

This question is similar to: How do I instruct Python to use my own compiled SQLite3?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
